# Java synchronization with callback

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I am developing a module inside my system where based on some event the user has to receive sms.

I have the following situation

```
synchronized(notificationPhoneNumber)
{
    SmsProvider.sendSms(notificationPhoneNumber, smsText);
}
```

The code of the method sendSms is running asynchronious:

```
public static void send(final NotificationPhoneNumber npn, final String smsText)
{
    Thread smsSender = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
           //sms sending code runs here....
        }

    }); 

    smsSender.start();
}
```

So the question is how long is the notificationPhoneNumber object locked in this case? Is it going to be locked by the time the thread finishes its job or not?

Comment: In `send` method you don't start the thread, so nothing happened.

Comment: sorry i forgot to write the start() method:)

Answer (score 3):

As long as

```
 SmsProvider.sendSms(notificationPhoneNumber, smsText);
```

doesn't return. That means, your `sendsms()` method will create a thread and return. Just for that amount of time.

Also, if you start your thread in your method. The created thread will just hold the reference but not the lock after `sendsms()` returns.

The lock and synchronization are external to `sendsms()`. Whichever thread calls `sendsms()`
will acquire the lock and the code within `sendsms()` has no knowledge of it.

Comment: Well, if the method is void? Still the same?

Comment: Does it means that inside the run() method i can make modification of the NotificationPhoneNumber object without beeing woried that some other thread may use it?

Comment: No, its quite opposite to that. Because the new thread does not have lock on the shared object. To make `run()` thread-safe in this case, you will have to explicitly synchronize inside `run()`

Comment: 10x. that is what i wanted to know:)

Answer (score 1):

```
synchronized(notificationPhoneNumber){
    ...
}
```

Here `NotificationPhoneNumber` object will be locked untill synchronized block executed and once it is execution is over, Thread will release the lock of that Object.

> A synchronized statement acquires a mutual-exclusion lock (§17.1) on
>   behalf of the executing thread, executes a block, then releases the
>   lock. While the executing thread owns the lock, no other thread may
>   acquire the lock.

[read more on documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.19)